# liferay process files which are uploaded

Tags: file-upload, liferay, liferay-hook

I'm new to Liferay, and I need to create hook which will intercept file and process it before save to the filesystem. Is it possible to do with hooks or I need to make ext?

Comment: Do you really need to intercept document BEFORE it is actualy stored to filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect this to work in a hook. Create a hook that intercepts `DLFileEntryLocalService`, e.g. `addFileEntry`. Do your job in that method and if you want to approve this to be added to the database, call `super.addFileEntry(...)` which will take care of the default behaviour.

You'll have to identify if there are more methods that can add a document to the library.